# gnuplot : Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I just now installed gnuplot 4.6.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 from the source by using standard `configure make make install`. But I am not able to plot anything after that. Something like this happens:

```
gnuplot> pl x
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I couldn't find any solution online for this particular problem. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit** : I wrote the same command in text file and tried running gnuplot on that file with:

```
gnuplot test.plt
```

It gives some hint about what could be the issue:

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),
and your program used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1009,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
```

Here is all linked libraries:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7729000)
libreadline.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0xb76ca000)
libgd.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3 (0xb7664000)
liblua5.1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0 (0xb7635000)
libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0 (0xb7303000)
libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0 (0xb71bf000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb71b2000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xb7165000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xb7041000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb6fef000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb6ee3000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb6e34000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6d2c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6ce5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6cc7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6cab000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6afc000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb6ada000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0xb6a7e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb6a64000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb6a3c000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb699c000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb6961000)
libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 (0xb694e000)
libvpx.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.1 (0xb677d000)
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0xb6709000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6704000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb6294000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xb6270000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xb626c000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xb6266000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xb625d000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xb6247000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb6241000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0xb6237000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xb618e000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xb618a000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xb6180000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb615d000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xb6152000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb601e000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb600b000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb6002000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb5ffa000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb5fbc000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xb5e3b000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xb5e2b000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xb5e20000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xb5e14000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xb5e10000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb5e0c000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb5e06000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb772a000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb5ddd000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xb5db6000)
libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0xb5da7000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xb5d86000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xb5d6c000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xb5d65000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xb5d0e000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0xb5d05000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb5d01000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb5cfa000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xb5cd6000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xb5cbe000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xb5c98000)
```

Comment: what does `ldd gnuplot` returns? (replace gnuplot to the full path to gnuplot) and please provide the version of gnuplot (`show version` in gnuplot terminal)

Comment: what compiler did you use to compile Gnuplot?

Comment: @bibi: `snehal@snehal-ThinkCentre-Edge-72z:~$ ldd gnuplot
ldd: ./gnuplot: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @ewcz: I installed it from source directly using standard configure make make install.

Comment: `ldd \`which gnuplot\``

Comment: @bibi : A very long list indeed. This is the complete output : http://www.beetxt.com/ZsO/3p29eW

Comment: Ok it's strange that these are 32bit versions of the libraries. Can you post the output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: @bibi: This is the output `3.13.0-95-generic #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 17:05:16 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Ok so it is coherent... I don't know try to rebuild the latest version. https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/latest/download?source=files

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the problem on a fresh 32bit installation of Ubuntu 14.04.5 (with Gnuplot 4.6.6). As the error message reveals, the issue is related with the `wxWidgets` library (providing the `wxt` terminal) due to ABI inconsistencies. This suggests that Gnuplot was compiled with different version of `gcc` than was used to generate the library. For example [installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618474/how-to-install-the-latest-gcurrently-5-1-in-ubuntucurrently-14-04) gcc 5.x and using it to compile Gnuplot produces exactly the mentioned `Aborted (core dumped)` error.

To remedy this, one could:

1. abandon `wxt` terminal and digress to, e.g., `set terminal x11`
2. recompile Gnuplot with the Ubuntu's 14.04 original `gcc` 4.8.x
3. enforce older ABI:

   ```
   export CXXFLAGS="-fabi-version=2"
   ./configure [your options] && make && make install
   ```

Comment: I was using 4.6.6 Before and tried installing 5.x but couldn't install it because when I run `make`, I get error : `This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options`. Can you help me with this?

Comment: 4.6.6 and 5.x now refers to Gnuplot or gcc?

Comment: Refers to the gnuplot